# merging previously merged objects in Seurat

Tags: r, seurat

I have two Seurat objects that were made by merging of samples:

```
object1 <-merge(A, y=B, add.cell.ids=c("A","B"))
object2 <-merge(C, y=D, add.cell.ids=c("C","D"))
```

For each object I did all preprocessing, PCA, and clustering. Now I want to merge cluster 1 from object1 and cluster 3 from object2

```
cluster1<-subset(object1, ident=1)
cluster3<-subset(object2, ident=1)

clusters1_3<-merge(cluster1, y=cluster3, add.cell.ids=c("1","3"))
```

however, when I cluster the cluster1_3 object, it would cluster to A, B, C, D initial clusters. What am I doinng wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your different objects would have different PCAs. When you merge the seurat objects, the PCA scores, clustering and tsne representations are copied, so there is no recalculation.

One option would be to normalize the data again, run PCA etc and re cluster, using a quick example:

```
library(Seurat)
library(patchwork)

process = function(x,id){
          x = RenameCells(x,paste0(id,"_",colnames(x)))
          x = SCTransform(x)
          x = RunPCA(x,npcs =10)
          x = RunTSNE(x,dims=1:10,perplexity=10)
          x = FindNeighbors(x,dims=1:10)
          x = FindClusters(x,algorithm=3,resolution=1)
          return(x)
}
          
i1 = sample(ncol(pbmc_small),60)
i2 = sample(ncol(pbmc_small),60)
object1 = process(pbmc_small[,i1],"A")
object2 = process(pbmc_small[,i2],"B")
```

Lets say we merge cluster1 from both objects:

```
FeaturePlot(object1,"CD14",label=TRUE,label.size=5) + FeaturePlot(object2,"CD14",label=TRUE,label.size=5)
```

[image]

You need to rerun the

```
cellsA<-subset(object1, ident=1)
cellsB<-subset(object2, ident=1)

clusters <-merge(cellsA, y=cellsB)
clusters = SCTransform(clusters)
clusters = SCTransform(clusters)
clusters = RunPCA(clusters)
[....]
```

If after this, you see still separation according to data, it is likely due to batch effects of your data and you need to [integrate the seurat objects](https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.0/integration.html)